# Morphia ArrayStoreException BigDecimal and Integer Array

Tags: java, morphia

I get the following stack trace when retrieving a document.
The document has a BigDecimal field that seem to be parsed successfully when running on the debugger.  However, the program crashes while parsing an array of five integer.

I note the use of BigDecimal because there are other posts mentioning BigDecimal and ArrayStoreException.

This error seems to indicate the array is being parsed to a List.

If I write the POJO from the Java code, the error is never seen.

But, if I add the BigDecimal as a string it shows this error.

How do I resolve this ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:361)
at org.mongodb.morphia.utils.ReflectionUtils.convertToArray(ReflectionUtils.java:538)
at org.mongodb.morphia.converters.IntegerConverter.decode(IntegerConverter.java:35)
at org.mongodb.morphia.converters.DefaultConverters.fromDBObject(DefaultConverters.java:133)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.ValueMapper.fromDBObject(ValueMapper.java:27)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.readMappedField(Mapper.java:601)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:582)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDBObject(Mapper.java:292)
at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.convertItem(MorphiaIterator.java:79)
at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.processItem(MorphiaIterator.java:65)
at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.next(MorphiaIterator.java:60)
at org.mongodb.morphia.query.QueryImpl.asList(QueryImpl.java:305)
```

This is the TypeConverter I use for the BigDecimal

```
public class BigDecimalConverter extends TypeConverter  implements SimpleValueConverter{

public BigDecimalConverter() {
    super(BigDecimal.class);
}

@Override
public Object encode(Object value, MappedField optionalExtraInfo) {
    BigDecimal val = (BigDecimal) value;
    if (val == null)
        return null;
    return val.toPlainString();
}

@Override
public Object decode(Class targetClass, Object fromDBObject,
        MappedField optionalExtraInfo) {
    if (fromDBObject == null)
        return null;
    BigDecimal dec = new BigDecimal(fromDBObject.toString());
    return dec;
}

}
```

The simplified POJO class is

```
@Entity(value = "a_table", noClassnameStored = true)
```

public class MorphiaArrayObject {
    @Id
    ObjectId Id;

```
@Property("ratings")
Integer[] ratings;

@Property("money")
BigDecimal money;

public ObjectId getId() {
    return Id;
}

public MorphiaArrayObject setId(ObjectId id) {
    Id = id;
    return this;
}

public Integer[] getRatings() {
    return ratings;
}

public MorphiaArrayObject setRatings(Integer[] ratings) {
    this.ratings = ratings;
    return this;
}

public BigDecimal getMoney() {
    return money;
}

public MorphiaArrayObject setMoney(BigDecimal money) {
    this.money = money;
    return this;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MorphiaArrayObject [Id=" + Id + ", ratings="
            + Arrays.toString(ratings) + ", money=" + money + "]";
}
}
```

If you add the document using morphia, read and write works find.  As done with the following code:

```
MorphiaArrayObject obj = new MorphiaArrayObject();
    obj.setMoney(new BigDecimal("1000000.00"));
    obj.setRatings(new Integer[]{4, 7, 8, 9});

    Db.save(obj);
```

But if you add the object from the javascript shell, I get the error when reading the object added from the shell using the morphia code:

db.a_table.insert( { money : "345.0" , ratings : [ 4, 5, 9, 8] } );

Comment: IMHO the BigDecimalConverter is fine, I'm using something very similar: https://github.com/xeraa/mongouk2011/blob/53bb667f8227349aaea7b79607a9ff28af691e02/src/main/java/at/ac/tuwien/ec/mongouk2011/persistence/BigDecimalConverter.java
Could you add the code snippet of the array part as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with using arrays:

Integer[] ratings;

I stopped using arrays on morphia and instead started using List and that works around the problem.